# Angular material ng-messages not showing correctly

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material, ng-messages

I'm using angular-messages to display form validation errors on my angular app

**DEMO**

http://jsbin.com/sutahixima/edit?html,js,output

Unfortunately, these three messages are showing perpetually. Regardless of what I type in the input field, be it a valid name or not. Both messages are always showing. If I try to only include one ng-message, the result is the same.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I managed to fix it

**DEMO**

http://jsbin.com/cubafoluji/1/edit?html,js,output

Basically what I did is:

1. Add the script to load the ngMessages (Try to load scripts at the end of the document for your project, just a suggestion):

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-messages.js"></script>`

2. In the messages container you have the ng-message wrong, you need to use the input **name**, also I used ng-if, in my opinion it's more reliable:

`<div
    ng-messages="accountSignup.firstname.$error"
    ng-if="accountSignup.firstname.$dirty"
    role="alert">`

3. In the js, I loaded the ngMessages as a module:

`var module = angular.module('test', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);`

I noticed you used Angular Material, there is a known issue with messages:
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2781

That's my source of info for the fix, I hope it works for you.

PD: I changed the min, max and require in the html to ng-min.... you don't need to change it if you don't want, it works with both but I suggest to use it to avoid any unexpected behavior.